# ManipulationDelta on pivot item only fires once

Tags: xaml, events, windows-phone-8, gesture

I am trying to animate an image based on the select pivoted items position.

I am currently using the ManipulationDelta event to try and see which direction the user is swiping so that I can fade out or fade in an animated image based on the position of the pivot item.

My problem is with the ManipulationDelta event, this event is only ever called once on a pivot item, regardless of how much manipulation of the pivot control is occurring.

Does anyone know a way to make it so the pivot items ManpulationDelta event is constantly called when it is being manipulated?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `Pivot` is intercepting further events. You may try to do such a thing - disable `Pivot` (then your Manipulations should work) and change `PivotItems` manually for example using [TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827740.aspx) and [Touch.FrameReported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.input.touch.framereported%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Sample code:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   myPivot.IsHitTestVisible = false; // disable your Pivot
   Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
   TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.HorizontalDrag; 
}

TouchPoint first;
private const int detectRightGesture = 20;

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(this);
    if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down)
        first = mainTouch;
    else if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up && TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        if (mainTouch.Position.X - first.Position.X < -detectRightGesture)
        {
            if (myPivot.SelectedIndex < myPivot.Items.Count - 1) myPivot.SelectedIndex++;
            else myPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else if (mainTouch.Position.X - first.Position.X > detectRightGesture)           
        {
            if (myPivot.SelectedIndex > 0) myPivot.SelectedIndex--;
            else myPivot.SelectedIndex = myPivot.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works to a degree, but you lose the manual manipulation of the pivot control. Cheers anyway this did help as a starting ground for me.

Comment: @TomWiddowson Yes, if you don't want Pivot to intercept events, you have to disable it. I'm glad it helped somehow ;)