# UWP Win 10 Tinder swipe card inside Pivot?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

Firstly here's the link to my [minimal version project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=72A2505C9C6FA57C!5967&authkey=!APbQE6aWmUecHvw&ithint=file%2Czip).
I am trying to create a tinder swipe card kind of effect inside my Pivot Page.
After referring [Lightstone Carousel](https://github.com/Mimetis/LightStone) Was able to create one in `C#` and `XAML` which works inside a `Grid`.
 Now my problem is that custom control should come inside a `Pivot` element. As pivot's default manipulation overrides my control's swipe Manipulation on *TOUCH* devices. How can I bubble down to my custom control.
Wasn't able to find `Touch`in Win 10 app as per [@Romasz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24198031/2898399) answer.
Any other control suggestion with similar effect would also be appreciated.
**XAML**

```
<Pivot>    
        <PivotItem>
            <Grid Background="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightBlue"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
                    <ctrl:Carrousel  Grid.Row="0" Background="Green"   ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}" 
                        SelectedIndex="0"
                        TransitionDuration="2500" 
                        Depth="700" 
                        MaxVisibleItems="15"
                        x:Name="CarrouselElement"
                        Rotation="50" 
                        TranslateY="0"
                        TranslateX ="1200">
                        <ctrl:Carrousel.EasingFunction>
                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                        </ctrl:Carrousel.EasingFunction>
                        <ctrl:Carrousel.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="Red">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="#bfbfbf" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding BitmapImage}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                                            <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="White">
                                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title}"  FontSize="16" Margin="4"/>
                                            </Border>                                              
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Height="12" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#bfbfbf"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Grid>    
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ctrl:Carrousel.ItemTemplate>
                    </ctrl:Carrousel>
                </Grid>  
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
        </PivotItem>    
    </Pivot>
```

As per @Chris W. query following two show the Tinder swipe effect
1) [Web Version](http://codepen.io/developingidea/pen/meAIn)
2) [Objective C Code](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards)

To see similar effect in app remove the encasing pivot control and pivot items and it would work fine.

**EDIT**
As per @Romasz comment have uploaded a [new sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9CBF79596200CAA!217306&authkey=!AGwP9j9fqqObJhI&ithint=file%2Czip). There are two upper one being my custom control where left and right swipe now works but vertical swipe doesn't. Below is default ListView where scroll swipe everything works but there is no Tinder kind effect. The only reason of creating the control is to add effect.

Comment: Sorry man never used Tinder, you got a visual example we could see that doesn't require going and loading up other projects?

Comment: Sorry didnt realize that. Have updated the question with reference links of the same pls have a look to get the basic idea.

Comment: How about disable the swipe behavior of pivot control?

Comment: @TuấnTrần thats the general idea. Currently I am not able to do it, without sacrificing the swipe feature of my custom control. How can I do that without hindering the functionality of my control.

Comment: I haven't run your sample yet, but have a question: if your control is inside pivot and it also requires swipe, then how you distinguish change on control from changing pivot item?

Comment: @Romasz On windows phone and Desktop simulator where touch is enabled the default swipe behavior of pivot item overrides that of my control. Since in windows 10 haven't been able to find touch events I am at a loss on how to identify the scroll on my control. The exact tree structure is Pivotitem->Scrollviewer->(now inside a grid there are many items while my custom control resides almost at bottom) The swipe on rest work as expected but when one scrolls to this control instead of bubbling down to control it uses default swipe of pivot.

Comment: So if I understand correctly - when swiping on other items above your control, the pivot item shoudl change, and once you swipe on your control it should handle the event. Is that what you try to achieve?

Comment: Yes absolutely right. But pivot should also change once user swipes the last element on control. Similar to a Listview with items arranged horizontally- the pivot scroll works on rest items but once it reaches the listview its inbuilt scroll starts and Pivot changes only when user swipes on last item.

Comment: I've tried your code. Can you try to add ManipulationMode to your carrousel: `<ctrl:Carrousel ManipulationMode="All" ... (rest of code)` - is this what you want to achieve? As far as I've tested swiping on image changes them, and swiping outside changes pivot item. Generally pointer events from the carrousel are not passed to pivot's scrollviewer in this case.

Comment: @Romasz that fixed the swiping issue but now vertical scroll of scrollviewer over it wont work(currently not present in sample). Along with no changing of pivot item when it reaches last element. Its now acting as a patch-like a webview where iteractions over it wont bubble up or down. Here is a [Sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9CBF79596200CAA!217306&authkey=!AGwP9j9fqqObJhI&ithint=file%2czip) as you can see my vertical scroll wont work when I swipe over it. Any way in which I can change the pivot item when I swipe on last item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your second sample, add `ManipulationMode="System,TranslateX"` to your carrousel. This should allow to move scrollviewer vertically and swipe through images horizontally:

```xml
<ctrl:Carrousel  Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGreen" ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}" ManipulationMode="System,TranslateX"
                 SelectedIndex="0" TransitionDuration="2500" Depth="700" MaxVisibleItems="15" x:Name="CarrouselElement"
                 Rotation="50" TranslateY="0" TranslateX ="1200">
```

There will be only just one problem - while the vertical scrollviewer is working and you swipe left/right, even on carrousel, the pivot will react with the change of item. There are two ways in this situation, I think:

- first, disable inertia of your scrollviewer - `IsScrollInertiaEnabled="False"`. But, as this solution doesn't look nice, I thought about different way,
- second, disable pivot while the scrollviewer is working. For this case you will have to subscribe to *ViewChanged* event of your scrollviewer and control pivot's *IsLocked* property:

  ```xml
  <ScrollViewer ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  ```

  in the code behind (I've also named your pivot):

  ```
  private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e) => myPivot.IsLocked = e.IsIntermediate;
  ```

As for changing pivot upon first/last element, I think you should be able to handle this by modifying a little the carrousel - provide events informing about the first/last item. Upon this you can invoke the pivot change.

Comment: Wow that did the trick. Awesome. Since I want to create a universal control which I can use on every page. How do you think I should handle the pivot page change on swipe. As getting the last or first item number can be done by attaching a property to my usercontrol and setting its value. Under which event of mainpage(as pivot is present on that page) should I specify to check the current item index. Will I have to add this event on all pages where I am planning to use this control.

Comment: @Jerin If I understood you correct, I would follow different path - instead of defining a property, implement you carrousel with event which will be fired once the item is last/first and user wants to switch to next. Then you can subscribe in your page and change pivot item.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I've done in one of my apps

You can review it here: [Universal Logo Maker for Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh5zchk) (head to setting page)

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Pivot Grid.Row="0" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <PivotItem x:Uid="SettingPage_PivotItem1" Header="Save location" />
        <PivotItem x:Uid="SettnigPage_PivotItem2" Header="About" />
        <PivotItem x:Uid="SettnigPage_PivotItem3" Header="Rate and Feedback" />
        <PivotItem x:Uid="SettnigPage_PivotItem4" Header="Update Database" />
        <PivotItem x:Uid="SettnigPage_PivotItem5" Header="Language" />
        <!--<PivotItem Header="More apps" />-->
    </Pivot>

    <Frame x:Name="SettingFrame"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="12,0,0,0" />

</Grid>
```

And here is the Pivot_SelectionChanged event handler

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pivot p = sender as Pivot;
        switch (p.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case -1:
                break;
            case 0:
                //Save location
                SettingFrame.Navigate(typeof (SaveLocationSettingPage));
                break;
            case 1:
                //About
                SettingFrame.Navigate(typeof(AboutPage));
                break;
            case 2:
                //Rate and feedback
                SettingFrame.Navigate(typeof (RateAndFeedbackPage));
                break;
            case 3:
                //Update database
                SettingFrame.Navigate(typeof (UpdateDatabasePage));
                break;
            case 4:
                //Language setting
                SettingFrame.Navigate(typeof(LanguagePage));
                break;
        }
    }
```

By doing this way, you still have the tab UI as Pivot control support, but disable all swipe behavior.
Also, split the element that you will put inside Pivot Item into a new Page will make XAML code clearer, easier to maintain.

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Since your answer disables `Swipe behavior` completely, it isn't the desired effect that I need. As then it turns pivot item into buttons clicking on which you are just opening pages. Is there any way in which I can have default swipe behavior while I am swiping on my elements present inside pivot along with swiping on my custom control which is currently being overwritten.

Comment: No I'm afraid. The last resort is to completely modify Pivot Control, and set a custom dependency property to enable and disable swipe at will.